# How to ship java based web application in AWS cloud using docker

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, docker

We have build java web application which provides various REST API.. I would like to have painless deployment progress.. Here is desired scene..

Users -> Load Balancer -> AS1, AS2, AS3 ...

Here AS = Application Server (Tomcat on EC2) OR Docker instances (I will prefer docker instances)

First time Desired Flow:

1. Developer fires maven and builds .war file
2. We may develop script which will generate docker image using this .war file..
3. Executes steps which will float this dockers behind ELB

Redeployment:

1. Developer fires maven and builds .war file
2. We may develop script which will generate docker image using this .war file..
3. Executes steps which will float this dockers behind ELB and destroy previous one..

I am kind of new to DevOps and may be doing some mistake in above steps.  So please feel free to correct me and provide guidance to achieve this goal.

(If this is duplicate please provide link to related question)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First Tomcat is not an application server. Furthermore by using which library are you developing REST API ? Many of them already provide an self contained setup to simply start them via `java -jar ...` including a servlet engine like jetty etc...Than the question comes if you really need to create a war file ?

Comment: Apart from that i would recommend to prevent developing scripts to create the docker images..there are already existing solutions either [docker-maven-plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) just to name an example... Furthermore I would recommend to let build etc. a CI solution like Jenkins do run all the stuff...